# Libgdx - Optimizing the usage of TextureRegion, also is there an upper bound on texture size?

Tags: libgdx, rendering

In an attempt to make my stuff faster, I was going to put all my graphics and sprites on a single huge texture (as recommended). However this would include all the graphics, not just a tile map of the same sized dimension (so it'd have 4x4's, 16x16's, maybe some 256x128's ...etc).

1) Is there an upper bound of the size a `Texture` can be? Can I make for example, 256 x 393216 pixel texture from a `Pixmap` and be okay with passing it off to the GPU? No performance penalties or any unexpected weirdness I should expect? Is there an upper bound to the size I can send or is that strictly dependent on hardware memory constraints?

2) Does it matter where my `TextureRegion` x/y offsets are? Example:

```
int x = 16;
int y = 23;  // Should this be some power of two?
int width = 16;
int height = 16;
new TextureRegion(x, y, width, height);
```

Is the above okay for speed as long as the width/height are powers of two? Or should I align `x` and `y` with some power of two boundary?

Comment: The texture size limit varies by GPU. 2048x2048 is safe for all Android devices. Many modern devices support 4096x4096, but then you have to check at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24103153/506796

Comment: TextureRegion offsets and size can be anything and have no effect on performance.