# Spritebatch not drawing anything LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

This is one of the oddest things that has ever occured in LibGDX for me. I have used these exact specifications for all my other States in my game, but under different names and they all work fine, except for my ShopState, which won't render ANYTHING at all! Here's my code for the class:

```
public class ShopState extends State{
    private Texture bg;
    private Sprite shopLayout;
    private OrthographicCamera shopCam;
    Viewport viewport;

    public ShopState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        shopLayout = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("shopLayout.png")));
        bg = new Texture("bg2.png");
        shopCam = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280, shopCam);
        viewport.apply();
        shopCam.position.set(shopCam.viewportWidth / 2, shopCam.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        shopLayout.setPosition(shopCam.viewportWidth / 2 - shopLayout.getWidth() / 2, shopCam.viewportHeight / 2 - shopLayout.getHeight() / 2);
        shopLayout.setSize(650, 1100);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();

    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height){
        viewport.update(width, height);
        shopCam.position.set(shopCam.viewportWidth / 2, shopCam.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        shopCam.update();
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(shopCam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(bg, 0 , 0, shopCam.viewportWidth, shopCam.viewportHeight);
        shopLayout.draw(sb);
        sb.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        bg.dispose();
        shopLayout.getTexture().dispose();

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything seems fine, but all I get when I click on the Shop button, it gives me a black screen!

Comment: what is default size of shopLayout.png ??

Comment: Does it matter? I changed its size anyways.

Comment: before setting new size you are using it to set position of shopLayout.

Comment: Put the setSize before the setPosition, Still not working

Comment: size of shopLayout.png and bg2.png should be less than 2048 in either side(width or height).

Comment: show me code of State class. ??

Comment: 1. They are less than 2048.

Comment: 2. Their size is modified anyways, so what is the point in asking their sizes?

Comment: 3. The state class doesn't matter, since all the other states work fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101711/is-there-a-max-libgdx-texture-size-for-desktop

Comment: The images resoultion's are fine. Why is my spritebatch not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution, but I have no idea why this fixes it. All I had to do was add a stage that uses the current viewport.

```
stage = Stage(viewport);
```

And that was it! It is now working properly, for some reason...