# Texture renders black to large FBO (qt QGLFramebufferObject)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, texture2d, fbo

Im rendering to texture using qt `QGLFramebufferObject`, when i am using FBO about 2000x2000 widthxheight its displays correctly, but when the size exceeds about 2750x2750 the texture displays black. It works with 2000x3000 or 2800x2500 so the product of the size must be less then about 7.5 millions

here render to fbo texture code:

```
makeCurrent();
saveGLState();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glViewport(0, 0, figureFBO->size().width(), figureFBO->size().height());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

figureFBO->bind();
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::yellow);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    qglColor(Qt::blue);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.constData());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
}
figureFBO->release();
restoreGLState();
```

and here code that display texture from FBO

```
    makeCurrent();
    qglClearColor(Qt::darkRed);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    qglColor(Qt::white);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureVertices.constData());
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.constData());
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, figureFBO->texture());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

Comment: I suspect that buffer is too large for your graphics card to create, use `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` to query the max size (be wary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758209/confusion-with-gl-max-texture-size).  Why do you need such a large FBO?

Comment: Thanks, `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`  returns 4096

Comment: i tried to render textures to fbo and then display fbo - it works with large fbo 4096x4096, where is the problem when i draw primitives to fbo?